# pth Quantile of Standard Normal Distribution - R

Tags: r, statistics, quantile

I'm learning statistics and R from a book called "Discovering Statistics using R"... Although it's very informative, it seems to skip over areas even though it suggests no prior knowledge of statistics or R is needed. So to the problem:

How can you calculate in R the pth quantile of the Standard Normal Distribution using the [Dichotomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomy) (or division in halves) method? (and assuming no use of `qnorm()`). that is:

```
    pnorm(x)   = p
    pnorm(x)-p = 0
    f (x)      = 0
```

**Update:**

Dichotomy is a method where you take an interval `[a,b]` which takes values of different
signs at the end points of the interval and has a single root `x` within `[a,b]`. You then half if to find `F(x1)`, and if `f(x1) != 0` it gives you `[a,x1]` and `[x1,b]`... where the sequence `x1, x2,...,` converges to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clumsy, but this works:

```
tolerance <- 1e-6
interval <- c(-1000,1000)
quantile <- 0.2

while(interval[2]-interval[1] > tolerance) {
  cat('current interval: ',interval,'\n')
  interval.left <- c(interval[1],mean(interval))
  interval.right <- c(mean(interval),interval[2])
  if(sum(sign(pnorm(interval.left)-quantile))==0) {
    interval <- interval.left
  } else {
    interval <- interval.right
  }
}
mean(interval)
qnorm(quantile)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for taking the time to post. I think it's a nice implementation. :D